# Need to find out the value for a given date by using Mongo DB

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

```
{
_id:"id-1",
createdDate:new Date("2020-01-01"),
"eventH":[{
    date: new Date("2020-01-01"),
    attribute1: value,
    attribute2: "value"
},
{
    date: new Date("2020-02-01"),
    attribute1:value,
    attribute2:"value"
},
{
    date: new Date("2020-02-20"),
    attribute1:value,
    attribute2:"value"
},
{
    date: new Date("2020-02-28"),
    attribute1:value,
    attribute1:"value"
},
{
    date: new Date("2020-03-05"),
    attribute1: value,
    attribute2:"value"
}]
},
{
_id:"id-2",
createdDate:new Date("2020-01-02"),
eventH:[{
    date: new Date("2020-01-02"),
    attribute1: value,
    attribute2: "value"
},
{
    date: new Date("2020-02-01"),
    attribute1:value,
    attribute2:"value"
},
{
    date: new Date("2020-02-20"),
    attribute1:value,
    attribute2:"value"
},
{
    date: new Date("2020-02-28"),
    attribute1:value,
    attribute2:"value"
},
{
    date: new Date("2020-03-05"),
    attribute1: value,
    attribute2:"value"
}]
},
{
_id:"id-3",
createdDate:new Date("2020-01-02"),
eventH:[{
    date: new Date("2020-01-02"),
    attribute1: value,
    attribute2: "value"
},
{
    date: new Date("2020-02-01"),
    attribute1:value,
    attribute2:"value"
},
{
    date: new Date("2020-02-20"),
    attribute1:value,
    attribute2:"value"
},
{
    date: new Date("2020-02-28"),
    attribute1:value,
    attribute2:"value"
},
{
    date: new Date("2020-03-05"),
    attribute1: value,
    attribute2:"value"
}]
},
{
_id:"id-4",
createdDate:new Date("2020-01-02"),
eventH:[{
    date: new Date("2020-01-02"),
    attribute1: value,
    attribute2: "value"
},
{
    date: new Date("2020-02-01"),
    attribute1:value,
    attribute2:"value"
},
{
    date: new Date("2020-02-20"),
    attribute1:value,
    attribute2:"value"
},
{
    date: new Date("2020-02-28"),
    attribute1: value,
    attribute2: "value"
},
{
    date: new Date("2020-03-05"),
    attribute1: value,
    attribute2:"value"
}]
}
```

---

Assume that above is the schema that is available to me in the data base.
Objective: For a given date find out the values of attribute1 and attribute2 and if it matches with what i am looking for then it is counted otherwise not.
Please note that eventH is an array that contains the attributes values which are changed over the period of time.

For ex : As of 5th March 2020, give me the documents that has attribute1 = value1 and attribute2= value2
I want to process it directly at Mongodb. Although i can process it by using pandas, but for larger data set and larger eventH object, there will be latency.Correct me if i am wrong.

Date can be any value for ex for 29 March 2020,the last value for the id-1 would be the value which was on 5th March 2020.
or
Value on 27 Feb 2020 for id-1 would be same as which was on 20 Feb 2020 because after 20 Feb 2020 the value got changed on 28 th Feb 2020, so if i query for 28 Feb 2020, it should give me value as of that date.

---

Comment: This is just a list of requirements, do you have a specific technical question? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: @AMC : This is not the list of requirements. It is just one problem statement. Although in pandas i have done the implementation by using df whereas trying to implement same on the mongo db . Not having much knowledge of Aggregation pipelines and map-reduce functions.If you can help me with a small hint it will be great.

Answer (score 0):

I think the below query is what you are looking for.

```
db.test2.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "eventH": {
                "$filter": {
                    "input": "$eventH",
                    "as": "arrayElem",
                    "cond": {
                        "$and": [
                            {"$eq": ["$$arrayElem.date", ISODate("2020-01-02T05:30:00.000+05:30")]},
                            {"$eq": ["$$arrayElem.attribute1", "value"]},
                            {"$eq": ["$$arrayElem.attribute2", "value"]},
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "eventH": {"$ne": []}
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This will help me to aggregate the data for the date that is part of db for ex it will give me the data for the elements that have date = new Date("2020-01-02"). Let us assume for date "2020-01-02", some values of attributes got changed and they are recorded as part of event H. New change in the value of attributes happens on 2020-01-06. and after that next change happened on 2020-01-31. My intention is to write a query where if i query for 2020-01-03 or 2020-01-05: The value should be same as of 2020-01-02 because after 2nd Jan the value changed on 6th Jan 2020

Comment: @BatScream Can you help?